# Angular and receiving stream from api

Tags: c#, angular

I am trying to receive from Web.API a event stream using angular 6 version so my API method looks simple enaught:

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("GetValues")]
    public async Task GetValues()
    {
        try
        {
            //Get values from db

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                byte[] dataItemBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonResponse);
                await Response.Body.WriteAsync(dataItemBytes,0, dataItemBytes.Length);
                await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

So now I was trying to use something like:

```
return this.httpClient.get<any>(http://localhost/api/System/GetValues`);
```

And all that I am receiving is

> Http failure during parsing for https://localhost/api/System/GetValues

So idea is I am sending request and reviving stream (stream will transfer lots of data that's why I used it) in return, it works on swagger and it also works on postman. But I am having problem with angular, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient.get() expects a single response, and that's not what your method is sending. Server Side Events are handled a little bit differently in JavaScript - check [EventSource docs in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).

By following a simple, nice implementation example (that runs everything within NgZone) from [here](https://bartoszgajda.com/2019/12/22/angular-and-server-sent-events-sse/):

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {}
  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.next(event);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = error => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          observer.error(error);
        });
      };
    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }
}
```

This creates a nice wrapper for handling SSE - you can use it as a equivalent of httpClient.get():

```
this.sseService
  .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost/api/System/GetValues")
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: link to bartoszgajda no longer works, but Internet Archive has it

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210619213648/https://bartoszgajda.com/2019/12/22/angular-and-server-sent-events-sse/

Comment: Also, SseService just keeps repeating the request for me after each one completes. In the eventSource.onerror, I added a call to `eventSource.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

try with specifying  `responseType: 'text'`

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(http://localhost/api/System/GetValues`, 
     { ...options, responseType: 'text' });
```